# regular expression to extract google places result

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-8, google-places-api

I am writing a Windows Phone application that is utilizing the Google Places Autocomplete API. The results are being returned as follows :

- Northern Caribbean University, Mandeville, Manchester Parish, Jamaica
- Spanish Town, Saint Catherine Parish, Jamaica
- New Harbour Village,Old Harbour, Saint Catherine Parish, Jamaica

Is there a way for me to get everything before the Parish part i.e before "Manchester Parish" or "Saint Catherine Parish" using a regular expression or something.

Comment: explain "before the Parish part". using first one as example, do you want "Manchester"? or "Northern Caribbean University, Mandeville,"?  or "Northern Caribbean University, Mandeville, Manchester" ?

Comment: I want "Northern Caribbean University, Mandeville" or "Spanish Town" or "New Harbour Village,Old Harbour"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm

1. split the string into an array. Split on `,`
2. loop through array.  return items until you find an entry containing parish, stop processing or split your array here.   ( any item containing Parish matches `^.*[Pp]arish.*$` )
3. convert what you have back to a string again if desired

-- Or --

If you just want to capture the portion before the Parish item and be done then use a positive lookahead like this:

```
.*(?=,[^,]*[Pp]arish)
```

### [Fiddle](http://fiddle.re/6mk06)

*Fiddle has a more explicit capture group if you need it and your examples are shown*